# GSP PubSub topic with proto schema - TimeStamp validation error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timestamp, google-cloud-pubsub, proto

I would like to use GCP PubSub with proto schema validation where messages will be in JSON. A part of the message is also `TimeStamp` so I added `TimeStamp` definition into the message (because imports are not supported) and my schema definition looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message NewSourceEvent {
  message Source {
      Timestamp time = 1;
      string username = 2;
  }

  message Timestamp {
    int64 seconds = 1;
    int32 nanos = 2;
  }

  Source source = 1;
}
```

Test message:

```
{
    "source": {
       "time": "1999-05-11T05:17:10Z",
       "username": "un"
    }    
}
```

And when I test the message from my service (which is serialized protobuf object into JSON) it's failed because it cannot serialize the TimeStamp - `Invalid schema message: (source.time): invalid value "1999-05-11T05:17:10Z" for type type.googleapis.com/NewSourceEvent.Timestamp.`

Is there any way how to define the schema to be able to parse the message and `time` will be still `TimeStamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `timestamp` type is imported from a external definition, like `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`

**BUT**, Pub/Sub does not support external `import` for now, as you [check here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas#:%7E:text=For%20a%20schema%20to%20work%20with%20Pub/Sub%2C%20only%20one%20top%2Dlevel%20type%20may%20be%20defined.%20Import%20statements%20to%20reference%20other%20types%20are%20also%20not%20supported.) , so I'm afraid it's not going to work. The workaround would be change it to `string` type.

I could not find a way to enable imports or to use timestamp without it.

---

The definition you have created is actually validating a message like this:

```
{ 
 "source":{
  "time":{
   "seconds":"999",
   "nanos":"999"
 },
  "username":"un"
}
```

You could try using a unix timestamp format in a `int64` variable: `1643886443340` = `Thursday, February 3, 2022 11:07:23.340 AM`

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the TimeStamp definition from google's proto to the schema directly but the transformation from JSON time doesn't work which makes the message validation again schema a little bit useless for me :(

Comment: This definition alone does not cover the real needed things to make it work, unfortunately. Its just avoiding the schema check failure in your case. The following message is what is actually testing: `{
    "source": {
       "time": {"seconds":"999", "nanos":"999"},
       "username": "un"
    }    
}` it does not define the timestamp type, just a variable with 2 inside fields. Schema validation still quite useful to validate the number of fields and structure. I have added an additional information in the answer, for you to maybe use unix format in the timestamp.